# How does Python make Fourier curve fitting smoother in python?How to select order just like the curve fitting app in matlab

Tags: python

I use the following function for Fourier series fitting, but the curve is not smooth. How to make the curve smooth?

```
def fourier(x, *args):
    w = 2 * np.pi / 200
    ret = 0
    for deg in range(0, int(len(args) / 2) + 1):
        ret += args[deg] * np.cos(deg * w * x) + args[len(args) - deg - 1] * np.sin(deg * w * x)

    return ret
```

the effect is like this：
[Fourier_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuQdd.png)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe increasing the number of pieces may help you. Try `w = 2*np.pi/1000`.

Comment: thanks,but the curve seem to have changed little

Comment: Increasing the number of pieces doesn't affect the function; it will help you plot the function more precisely. For example, you were calculating the function for each `2pi/200` approximately 0.03 radians, now you are calculating `2pi/1000` 0.006 radians, which is more accurate. By increasing the number 1000, you can get more accurate plots.